# I need an regular expression for validate comma separated emails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-core

I am following Entity framework code first approach.
I have following property in one of my models.
I want to validate comma separated emails by this regular expression.
But it is not working fine.
Ex:

[image]
**As you can see it is validating here correctly.**

[image]
**But it doesn't work in here**

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$",ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
[DisplayName("Participant List")]
public string ParticipantList { get; set; }
```

Anyone know any regular expression that works properly, i would like to know. I am highly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For validating multiple emails in TextBox, you can use following regular expression

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*,\s*|\s*$))*$
```

Comment: Hi @Tanzim, I got an **RegexParseException**, `RegexParseException: Invalid pattern '^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)(\s*,\s*|\s*$))*$' at offset 16. [x-y] range in reverse order.`

Answer (score 0):

following regex matched if any email found (if an invalid email come after coma matched too)

```
((\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+),?)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/GZN1nY/1

---

this one matched to valid email separated by coma(not matched if any email is invalid)

```
^((\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+),?)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Oz7GkD/1

Comment: the 2nd one is working as just as the regular expression i am using now. (its validating `test@gmail.c` also as an valid email address) But i think i have simple misunderstanding about email addresses. I think if we have any suffix after "<prefix>@gmail." its considered as a valid email address. In that case `testemail@gmail.com, testemail@gmail.m,, testemail@gmail.co,` are all should considered as valid email in general. Don't know its correct or not. Any idea?

Comment: ```testemail@gmail.com, testemail@gmail.m,, testemail@gmail.co,``` this input is not valid in 2nd one that your can test it by regex101 link.
if you are looking for better email validation you should find by yourself and put it in ```^(EMAIL_REGEX,?)+$``` form